# Show a conjecture about $\arcsin\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)!>1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, examples-counterexamples, gamma-function

Recently I found the inequality :

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)!>1$$

I don't ask for a proof .

I ask if someone can give some details on the link with the Gamma function and arcsin .

I ask also because we have a formula on wiki page for the Gamma's function  wich gives an equality with the function $\sin$ .

But now why arcsin ?

Can we find a infinite series ?

---

---

---

I can gives some other terms of the "series" we want :

$$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)!\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{\frac{1}{80}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999}{10000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999}{100000}\right)^{\frac{1}{70}}\right)}>1$$

Edit :

I gives more terms :

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)!\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{\frac{1}{80}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999}{10000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999}{100000}\right)^{\frac{1}{70}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{999999}{1000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999999}{10000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{62}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999999}{100000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{999999999}{1000000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{85}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999999999}{10000000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999999999}{100000000000}\right)^{\frac{1}{79}}\right)}>1$$

And made a conjecture :

Let $a_k>0$ such that :

$$\arcsin\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)!\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{\frac{1}{a_{k}}}\right)}\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999}{10000}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999}{100000}\right)^{\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}}\right)}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{9999\cdot\cdot\cdot9}{1000\cdot\cdot\cdot00}\right)^{\frac{1}{600}}\right)}{\arcsin\left(\left(\frac{99999\cdot\cdot\cdot9}{10000\cdot\cdot\cdot00}\right)^{\frac{1}{a_{m}}}\right)}\cdot\cdot\cdot=1$$

Then I conjecture that for $a_1=80,a_2=70,a_3=62,a_4=85,a_5=79,a_6=61.75$:

$$a_k<100$$

How to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: I don't see why this inequality is interesting? It might be interesting to find which replacements to `9/10` and `6/10` (individually) yield equality to 1, but I don't see why 9/10 and 6/10 are inherently interesting here.

Comment: You should also try $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac7{10}\right)\left(-\frac3{10}\right)!,\sin^{-1}\left(\frac9{10}\right)\left(\frac3{10}\right)!>1$

Comment: Why even answer this?  Calculate it and be done.

Comment: Numerically, arcsin(9/10) = 1.1197695149986342, and (6/10)! = gamma(1.6) = 0.8935153492876903.  The product is 1.0005312493157121, which indeed is slightly greater than 1.  But so what?

Comment: Have a lokk at my update

Answer (score 2):

The solution to

$$\sin^{-1}\left(\frac32x\right)x!=1\implies x=0.59983…$$

is approximated by the series expansion of $x!$ about $x=\frac12$ and of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ about $x=\frac1{\sqrt3}$:

$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\left(\frac\pi3+3\left(x-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\right)=1\implies x=\frac1{\sqrt3}+\frac2{3\sqrt\pi}-\frac\pi9=0.60441…\approx\frac23$$

[More terms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28sqrt%28%CF%80%29%2F2+%2B+1%2F2+sqrt%28%CF%80%29+%28x+-+1%2F2%29+polygamma%280%2C+3%2F2%29+%29%28%CF%80%2F3+%2B+3+%28x+-+1%2Fsqrt%283%29%29+%29%3D1) give better approximations.

Comment: thanks for the answer can you look to my conjecture ?

Comment: @ErikSatie What “algorithm” did you use to find the expansion for the conjecture?

Comment: Nothing else than try and try .

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$f(\epsilon)=\sin ^{-1}(1-\epsilon^2 )\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}+\epsilon^2 \right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,\epsilon^n $$ where the first coefficients are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n \\
 0 & \frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & \frac{\pi  \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
 3 & -\frac{25}{12}+\gamma +\log (4) \\
 4 & \frac{\pi  \left(-8+\pi ^2+2 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right)}{8
   \sqrt{2}} \\
 5 & \frac{1}{480} \left(951-120 \pi ^2-40 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)
   \left(1+6 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\right) \\
 6 & \frac{\pi  \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \left(-24+3 \pi ^2+2 \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right)+2 \pi  \psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{24 \sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now compute the partial sums
$$S_p=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,10^{-n/2}  $$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & 1.392081999 \\
 1 & 0.995749269 \\
 2 & 1.000828973 \\
 3 & 0.996079983 \\
 4 & 1.002595858 \\
 5 & 1.000654391 \\
 6 & 1.000485853 \\
 7 & 1.000515895 \\
 8 & 1.000538616 \\
 9 & 1.000532116 \\
 10 & 1.000530898 \\
 11 & 1.000531186 \\
 12 & 1.000531278 \\
 13 & 1.000531254 \\
 14 & 1.000531248 \\
 15 & 1.000531249 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Otherwise, as @Tyma Gaidash did, starting with $\epsilon_0=0$, the first iterate of Newton method for $f(\epsilon)=1$ is
$$\epsilon_{(2)}=\frac{\pi ^{3/2}-4}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$ and, by Darboux theorem, we know that it is an underestimate of the solution since
$$\big[f(0)-1\big]f''(0)=\frac{1}{8} \pi ^{3/2} \left(\pi ^{3/2}-4\right) \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)~~>~0$$

Similarly, the first iterate of Halley method
$$\epsilon_{(3)}=\Bigg[\frac{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}{\pi ^{3/2}-4}-\frac{\pi  \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\Bigg]^{-1}$$ is an overestimate of the solution.

We can expand
$$f(\epsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\,(\epsilon-\epsilon_{(2)})^n $$

Computing again the partial sums

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & 1.004658787 \\
 1 & 1.000530217 \\
 2 & 1.000531249 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$f(\epsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\,(\epsilon-\epsilon_{(3)})^n $$ using only the first term gives $1.000531214$.

**Edit**

Pushing more and more
$$f\left(\frac{1159+686 \pi -116 \pi ^2}{324+227 \pi +589 \pi ^2}\right)=1.0000000000000000000250068\cdots$$

**Update**

It is interesting to look at the zero level plot of
$$f(x,y)=\sin ^{-1}(x)\,\, \Gamma (1+y)-1$$ (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5BArcSin%5Bx%5D*Gamma%5B1%2By%5D%3D%3D1%2C+%7Bx%2C+0.900%2C+0.905%7D%2C+%7By%2C+0.340%2C+0.610%7D%5D)).

Using the same approach as above, you could prove that
$$f\left(\frac{900}{1000},\frac{332}{1000}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f\left(\frac{900}{1000},\frac{596}{1000}\right)>0$$
$$f\left(\frac{901}{1000},\frac{349}{1000}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f\left(\frac{901}{1000},\frac{578}{1000}\right)>0$$
$$f\left(\frac{902}{1000},\frac{369}{1000}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f\left(\frac{902}{1000},\frac{557}{1000}\right)>0$$
$$f\left(\frac{903}{1000},\frac{395}{1000}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f\left(\frac{903}{1000},\frac{530}{1000}\right)>0$$
$$f\left(\frac{904}{1000},\frac{445}{1000}\right)>0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f\left(\frac{904}{1000},\frac{478}{1000}\right)>0$$

Comment: Dear Claude Leibovici all is interesting but can you show $a_k<100$ ? or disprove it in a short way ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. I also think that it is interesting. The contour plot is revealing a lot of things (I do not see them but my wife told me how many times I had to rescale). Now, concerning the $a_k$'s, you have such a talent that I shall not try to compete with you. One of these days (may be today ?), you will need to explain how you get them. Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude I'm like everyone (Desmos +WA) and the rest is luck . To stay in math the solution given by Tyma Gaidash is near from $$1+\frac{\left(-1-e+\pi\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$.

Comment: For the minimum of $x!$ for positive $x$ what do you think about :$$\left(\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\pi-e\right)}{2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}{2}\right)\left(\tanh\left(1\right)-\frac{3}{10}\right)\right)$$ found manually.